# Append List with reg. expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to append a list (null) with "sentences" which have # (Hashtags) from a different list. 
Currently my code is giving me a new list with length of total number of elements involved in the list and not single sentences.

The code snippet is given below

```
import re

old_list = ["I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!","But I dont #love hastags",
"So #what can you do","Some simple senetnece","where there is no hastags","however #one can be good"]

new_list = [ ]


for tt in range(0,len(s)):
    for ui in s:
        if bool(re.search(r"#(\w+)",s[tt])) == True :
            njio.append(s[tt])
```

Please let me know how to append only the single sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are wanting for output, but this will preserve the original sentence along with its matching set of hashtags:

```
>>> import re
>>> old_list = ["I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!","But I dont #love hastags",
... "So #what can you do","Some simple senetnece","where there is no hastags","however #one can be good"]
>>> hash_regex = re.compile('#(\w+)')
>>> [(hash_regex.findall(l), l) for l in old_list]
[(['stackoverflow', 'people', 'helpful'], 'I love #stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!'), (['love'], 'But I dont #love hastags'), (['what'], 'So #what can you do'), ([], 'Some simple senetnece'), ([], 'where there is no hastags'), (['one'], 'however #one can be good')]
```

Comment: @sberry... how to close this question.